# What is the "this" object inside a Meteor Template helper?

Tags: templates, meteor

When Blaze makes a call to a function defined inside a Template.xxx.helper, it passes one or more arguments. The first argument is an object which appears to be empty. What is it? What can it be used for?

Here's how to recreate my barebones test, using a Terminal window:

```
meteor create test
cd test
cat > test.html << EOF
<body>
  {{> test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  <p>{{test1 "data"}}</p>
  <p>{{test2 key="value"}}</p>
</template>
EOF
cat > test.js << EOF
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.test.helpers({
    test1: function (argument) {
      console.log(this, argument)
      return "test1 helper: " + argument
    }
  , test2: function (argument) {
      console.log(this, argument)
      return "test2 helper: " + argument.hash.key
    }
  });
}
EOF
meteor run
```

Here's what I see in the browser console, after expanding the hash object:

```
Object {} "data"
Object {} S…s.kw {hash: Object}
  hash: Object
    key: "value"
  __proto__: Object__proto__: Spacebars.kw
```

What is the `this` `Object {}`? 
And in particular, is there a way I can use it to discover which HTML element triggered the call?

Comment: Also see [A Guide to Meteor Templates & Data Contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside a template helper, `this` is the data context of your template instance.

In your example the data context is not set, so it is returning an empty object. But that is not always the case. Imagine the following example:

```
<template name='parent'>
  {{#with currentUser}}
    {{> child}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

In this case `Meteor.user()` has been set as the data context for the instance of `Template.child`, so `Meteor.user()` is bound to `this` in `Template.child.helpers()`. Which allows you to do the following:

```
Template.child.helpers({
  greeting: function(){
    console.log(this); // logs Meteor.user() || undefined
    return 'Welcome back ' + this.username;
  }
});
```

The data context can be set explicitly, via `each` or `with` blocks, or via parent template contexts. As in the example above you'll generally want to check against `undefined` when using `this` in helpers.

The short answer to your question whether `this` in a template helper can identify the DOM node(s) that invoke it is no. You *may* be able to dig it out of the helper's parameters via the prototype (I haven't checked), but I would consider this an antipattern. If you care where the helper is coming from, just include a parameter. Continuing the prior example:

```
<template name='child'>
  <p>{{greeting}}</p>
  <p>{{greeting 'special'}}</p>
</template>
```

And:

```
Template.child.helpers({
  greeting: function(str){
    if (str === 'special'){
      return 'Welcome to first class Ambassador ' + this.username;
    }
    return 'Please take your seat in coach ' + this.username;
  }
});
```